# How to create a simple UIViewController in Swift and set it as the starting view

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate, init

I would like to create a simple UIViewController and when I start the simulator it should be the first View that gets called. The content never loads though. For test purposes I only add a label.

Here is my UIViewController:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ViewControllerSearchGithubName:UIViewController {

    let lblName = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15, 15, 50, 50))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        lblName.text = "Name:"
        lblName.textColor = UIColor.cyanColor()
        self.view.addSubview(lblName)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

and my AppDelegate:

```
 func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

        self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)

       let viewController = ViewControllerSearchGithubName()

        let navc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        self.window?.rootViewController = navc
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true
    }
```

I apprecciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is working fine; your view controller and its view are behaving as expected. The problem is only that your label is at `15,15`, which is underneath the navigation bar and thus hidden by it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Solved it.

Comment: Glad to help. Very well asked question.